# issue with methods for find keywords , sort words

Tags: java

When the application is launched, it will ask the user to enter words one at a time. Once a word has been entered, it will ask if the user would like to add a new word. The user will continue adding words until they indicate they are done.

After all words have been entered, the application will output a report listing only the unique words. (No duplicate words should appear in the report.)

---

I have the issue with the function found word 
it should work like that :
program such that it contains a list of keywords. Place whatever words you choose into this list (hard coding in values is ok). When your program runs compare the user entered words to the list of keywords. Indicate on the output report which user-entered words were keywords.

Also, I have the issue with function sort String :
program such that the words are alphabetized in the output report.

The program works perfectly for the display words, but it doesn't work for Find keywords and match words also not working with sort alphabetized

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;          
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Collection;

public class LabNineKennel {

    private  InputHelper2  input;
    private  ArrayList<LabNine>    labNineWords;


    public void run() {
        entry();
        displaywords();    
        findWord();
    }

    public void entry()
        labNineWords = new ArrayList<LabNine>();
        input = new InputHelper2(); 
        String  word          = "";
        String  more          = "";
        LabNine     newLabNine        = null;
        // the method to take the information fron the user 
        while (true) {
            word = input.getUserInput(
                                      "Enter the name of the client");

            newLabNine = new LabNine();
            newLabNine.setWord(word);

            labNineWords.add(newLabNine);
            // ask the user again if he want to addd any other client
            more = input.getUserInput(
                                      "Would you like to enter another?");
            if (!more.equals("y")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public void displaywords() {
        LabNine  labnine  = null;
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("*****Your List Of Unique Word*********");
        for (int i = 0; i < labNineWords.size(); i++) {
            labnine = labNineWords.get(i);
            System.out.println(labnine.display());

        } 
        System.out.println( "\n*******************************************");

    }

    public void findWord() {
        // creat the private instance variable for class Kennel
        String [] codes = {"G22", "K13", "I30", "S20"};
        LabNine  labnine  = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < labNineWords.size(); i++) {
            boolean isValid = false;
            labnine = labNineWords.get(i);

            if (labnine.equals( codes)) {
                isValid = true;
            }else isValid = false;

            if (isValid = true)  {
                System.out.println(labnine.display2());
            }
        }
    }

    public  void sortString()
    {
        LabNine  labnine  = null;
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("*****Your List Of Unique Word*********");
        for (int i = 0; i < labNineWords.size(); i++) {
            labnine = labNineWords.get(i);
            Arrays.sort(labNineWords);
            System.out.println(labnine.display()); 
        }

    }     
}
```

---

The LabNine Class

```
// Creat a client class 
public class LabNine {

    // creat the private instance variable for class Client
    private String word;
    private String word1;
    private String word2;
    private String word3;
    private String word4;

    /**
     * Sets the value of word4.
     * @param word4 The value to assign word4.
     */
    public void setWord4(String word4) {
        this.word4 = word4;
    }



    /**
     * Sets the value of word3.
     * @param word3 The value to assign word3.
     */
    public void setWord3(String word3) {
        this.word3 = word3;
    }




    /**
     * Sets the value of word2.
     * @param word2 The value to assign word2.
     */
    public void setWord2(String word2) {
        this.word2 = word2;
    }




    /**
     * Sets the value of word1.
     * @param word1 The value to assign word1.
     */
    public void setWord1(String word1) {
        this.word1 = word1;
    }




    /**
     * Returns the value of word.
     */
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }


    /**
     * Sets the value of word.
     * @param word The value to assign word.
     */
    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }


    // creat the method display to display the data that user input
    public String display() {


        return   
                  "\n " + getWord();



    }
public String display2() {


    return "\n" + getWord() + "*";
}

}
```

Comment: Is it a homework question? Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) then.

Comment: For a start you are missing an opening `{` brace for your `entry()` method. The code you have posted here will not even compile.

Comment: i'm just asking about functionality of the two methods  that's it

Comment: everything is working right just two methods for find keywords and also the sort alphabetize

Comment: @GhebriouAbdallah Can you post the LabNine  class?

Comment: @GhebriouAbdallah Also, the if (isValid = true) check should be if (isValid == true) or even better if (isValid).

Comment: i'm new one here, i don't know how i share again

Comment: all what i need is two functions for find match words and also storWord

Comment: @GhebriouAbdallah Just edit your post(under your post, there is an edit option) and copy paste the code that is missing.

Comment: Done , i did , all what i want is my method to find match words works and also stor my words from A to Z

Comment: they don't work i tried so many time

Answer (score 1):

The line of code (labnine.equals(codes)) is checking if an Object is equal to an Array. This will return false.

This can be modified to the below to check if the **codes** does contain the word

```
    if ((Arrays.asList(codes).contains(labnine.getWord()))) {
        isValid = true;
    } else {
        isValid = false;
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient. One thing you'll create a new list on each iteration. The other one is `ArrayList.contains` is `O(n)`.

Comment: @lexicore - Didn't think performance was the criteria for the question. However, yes, there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: i input words they are not in the codes list , and output says they are in and that not true

Answer (score 0):

In the `findWord` you should check which words entered by the user are keywords. You iterate over words (`labNineWords`) but then check by simply doing `labnine.equals(codes)`. You are basically comparing an instance of `LabNine` with an array of strings here. Unless your `LabNine.equals` method is specially programmed so that it will check if the word denoted by the given `LabNine` instance is contained in the array (and I highly doubt it is programmed this way), this `equals` call will not produce results you expect.

An easier way is to create a set of keywords and simply check if `labnine.display()` (or however you get the string representation of the word) is contained in this set. Something along the lines:

```
private static final Set<String> KEYWORDS = 
    Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("G22", "K13", "I30", "S20")));

public void findWord() {
    for (int i = 0; i < labNineWords.size(); i++) {
        LabNine labnine = labNineWords.get(i);
        if (KEYWORDS.contains(labnine.display()) {
            // This is a keyword
            System.out.println(labnine.display2());
        }
    }
}
```

Next, sorting. You sort with `Arrays.sort`. This most probably won't even compile as your `labNineWords` is a collection, not an array. You can sort this list using `Collections.sort`. For this to work, either your `LabNine` class must implement `Comparable` or you have to provide a `Comparator`. Assuming you want to sort on `LabNine.display()`, you can easily construct a comparator with `Comparator.comparing(LabNine::display)`

Also you probably don't want to modify the original list, so better make a copy.

Something along the lines:

```
public void sortString()
{
    List<LabNine> sortedLabNineWords = new ArrayList<>(labNineWords);
    Collections.sort(sortedLabNineWords,
        Comparator.comparing(LabNine::display));
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("*****Your List Of Unique Word*********");
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedLabNineWords.size(); i++) {
        LabNine  labnine = sortedLabNineWords.get(i);
        System.out.println(labnine.display()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , how i can add the change to my functions to be working please

Comment: @GhebriouAbdallah I am sorry, this is very basic task, at least this is what you should be able to carry out on your own.

Comment: i put these functions in the program it shows a lot of errors

Comment: @GhebriouAbdallah I am sorry, I will not be able to help.

Comment: i got it , Thanks a lot for help sir

Comment: I fix the bugs but the function findWord still not working

Comment: i compile the program and i input G22 and gaga as words 
in the output : 
G22
gaga 
------------------------------

Comment: @GhebriouAbdallah Well, you'll have to debug it. The answer provides a little bit more than basic ideas for the problems you've posted. But it is your job to integrate it in your code.

Comment: the IF statement don't execute when i run the program , it should compare  , i'm not sure about it